# How to configure Netbeans subversion for large project with many svn:externals

Tags: svn, netbeans, symfony1, netbeans-6.9

In a project, we have several svn:includes to pull in the framework and some 3rd-party plugins. Because the framework (Symfony) itself includes numerous other nested libraries via svn:externals, it can take a long time for NetBeans to finish its background job of automatic "Scanning Projects".  It sometimes gets completely stuck while doing the "Checking for external changes" part.

I have tried to work around this by disabling the "Scan for external changes" but that seems to only reduce the frequency of the problem while introducing new inconveniences rather than solve it.

I'm hoping that someone knows a way to tell the SVN scan to ONLY look at OUR repository for changes (which should only take a couple of seconds), not the nested external repositories.  Similar to using the CLI svn update --ignore-externals command.

Background: Running NetBeans 6.9.1 on OS X 10.6.

Comment: Possibly off-topic, but have you considered using Maven instead of Subversion to manage the dependencies?

Comment: No, we're not really a java shop and have never used Maven at all.  Since CLI svn handles this situation efficiently, I don't think Subversion is the weakness here.  It's either something about how NetBeans is invoking svn under the hood, or some other process NetBeans is doing that I may be incorrectly attributing to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `--ignore-externals` to many svn subcommands, like `svn update --ignore-externals` or `svn st --ignore-externals` but you will have to see how you can make Netbeans do that as it has it's own svn client.

You can make Netbeans make use of commandline svn by using the following switch though:

```
-J-DsvnClientAdapterFactory=commandline
```

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSvnCli

But beyond that I do not have much knowledge of svn / netbeans to enforce this. One thing I had done in Windows with TortoiseGit was to point TortoiseGit to a git.cmd and do some processing there, and then make git.cmd call git.exe from msysgit. You can probably try that. Set path to some other script that you have control which will then call svn binary,something like below?

```
#!/bin/bash
svn $* --ignore-externals
```

and name it svn and make it executable and put it in path perhaps.

( make it check if the subcommand is update or status and then add the `--ignore-externals` if needed, as Netbeans I think just parses the output from svn command line client and an additional output of `Subcommand doesn't accept --ignore-externals` may screw up its processing )

Yeah, not a solid answer, but I wrote down my thought process.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm exploring this possibility though it's a lot messier than I'd hoped for.  I don't see that NetBeans has a way to specify a custom script instead of just svn.  That means if I try to install a custom wrapper script like you suggest, then it'll be getting called ALL of the time when I use svn, not just through NetBeans.  Unless I also figure out also how to determine whether the calling process is NetBeans to behave differently.

Comment: It's messy all right! I don't see any other options. If someone more experienced in Netbeans can answer, it will be great :)

Comment: I just gave you +1 because even though I have so far ONLY implemented the switch to force CLI svn under the hood, I have not yet had that problem recur.  It could be just a slow/buggy library that it uses by default.  If no easier or more thorough answers show up here, I'll accept yours as well.  Thanks much for the help!

Comment: also struggled with the SVN performance, added "run.args.extra=-J-DsvnClientAdapterFactory=commandline" into project.properties and it seems to work; at least for local repositories. that "background scanning of projects" still causes Java to roast the CPU (there are quite some files).